# Can not install Ubuntu 11.10 through USB Stick

Tags: 11.10, installation, wubi, usb-drive, windows-xp

After I successfully unpacked to a USB drive the ISO-image and ran wubi.exe, I chose the settings there within Windows and I restarted my computer and chose Ubuntu. But this gives me the error:

```
Try (hd0, 0): NTFS5: Error: prefix not set.
```

What should I do? I am installing Ubuntu on Windows XP with Wubi.

Comment: How did you "unpack" the ISO file to your usb drive ? Using a software like UnetBootin or you just right clicked and extracted it the ISO contents to your USB ?

Answer (score 0):

If the original poster still has a problem with this, try the solution  posted for this user, it explains how to mount the ISO correctly onto a USB within XP, that may have been the issue and so the .exe runs in XP but because it isn't correcly mounted the boot doesn't work: 
[Possible fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164108/ubuntu-12-04-installation-issue/164146#164146)