# Ubuntu isn't starting after unexpected shutdown

Tags: 11.10, boot-failure

Due to power cut, My PC went off. Then, when I opened it, Ubuntu wasn't starting. I tried to run Ubuntu from live CD, it's not working. Now, what should I do?  I can access BIOS and terminal from recovery mode.

Update:

I have 256,256 & 512 MB RAM installed in my PC. After unplugging two 256 MB RAM. I've only 512 MB RAM now and my PC now working fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your system show BIOS menu at initial startup.

Comment: Yes. I can access BIOS.

Comment: If you can access terminal, try `sudo update-grub` and `sudo reboot`

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS No. But, this question can be use as a reference for newbie.

Comment: Let's not use "newbie". I recommend beginner. I often help beginners locally and know from experience that they often consider "newbie" an insult.

Answer (score 2):

If you can still access your PC's Boot Menu you could try loading Ubuntu onto a USB and running it off there ([Check my answer here if you don't know how to do it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164108/ubuntu-12-04-installation-issue/164146#164146)) if you're fortunate that could work, otherwise could you please go into further detail:

- Firstly does you PC load to the boot screen when you turn it on? (if your hardware was damaged during the power cut as it,you're probably going to have to send it back to the manufacturer)
- Do you have access to the grub screen if you're dual booting?
- If you are dual booting can you still access your files from another OS?
- Does anything come up when you try running the live CD? Or no response at all?

**Edit:** I stumbled accross a fix for people who tried launching Ubuntu and ended up with a black screen, not sure if your issue is similar but this might be worth a shot if your graphics drivers had a bug because of the power-cut: [Potential fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076)

Comment: Yes, I've access the grub screen. It showing 4 menus Ubuntu, recovery mode,memory test. If I choose Ubuntu, nothing happen and I checked your solution, I already tried with many distro.

Comment: That's quite a strange thing to have, do you have any other distros installed alongside Ubuntu? (From which you could access your files on your Ubuntu partition) Also when you get the choice of [loading Ubuntu on the Grub](http://tombuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/grub2_menu.jpg) select your Ubuntu installation press 'e' to open up edit mode and write down the code and post it here, it may be that which for some reason was changed because of the power cut which means it doesn't run Ubuntu correctly even though it says it should.

Comment: No, I've no other distros installed in my PC.

Comment: I edited my answer @YasirAdnan I'm not sure if your problem is similar but worth a try if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug all devices from USB, exept keyboard and try again. Also if you have add-on cards inside of the PC, remove all but the vga card for now to see if it makes a difference.
Good Luck

Comment: OP stated in chat he is sure hardware is not damaged, and Ubuntu has booted previously. [Transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5412554#5412554)

Comment: Yes, my hardware isn't damaged. I can access everything from command line(recovery mode).

Comment: Well, sure that motherboard ,CPU and Mem are working if you can get into bios.Still it sounds like a init. problem caused by some hardware.  takes only a few minutes to rule that out and make sure

Answer (score 1):

I had something like this happen a few times and had to go through recovery mode and check the disk(s) and fix (needs to be plugged into Ethernet cable). I had it reinstall almost the whole Ubuntu operating system once. It completely recovered itself and fixed itself from not working at all. Only in LINUX!

I am just an amateur, maybe this helps.

Comment: I should explain a bit better: First I checked the hard-drive for bad sectors with "fdisk" (this can also be run from the command prompt). Then I "repaired broken packages" to restore the system.

Answer (score -3):

you need to turn the power back on or the computer will not start, and if it is a laptop make sure the battery is charged or if you don't have a battery plug in the ac adapter, if your trying to turn it on then make sure the power adapters are in, and you are getting electrical currents to your house.

Comment: He says he can access the bios, which I think means we can safely assume he knows what the power button does.

Comment: The OP can access BIOS. See the comments.

Comment: You sound like my ISP's tech support, whenever I have a problem and whatever the problem is, their solution is always to restart the router. :D

Comment: My ISP tells me that4 times before letting me speak to some call-center drawl telling me to "reboot your modem and try again"