# Ubuntu 12.04 not booting as it should

Tags: lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Good day all,

I have made the choice to reinstall my pc and use ubuntu 12.04 as the actual os and not win.

Usually I used ubuntu in a vm to play around and ready my knowledge for when when or rather if I would use it as the main os of my system.

A few days ago I loaded ubuntu on a laptop of mine for use as a web test server and internet sharing. This laptop gives me no problems apart from that it is old.

However, I got myself a new pc a few weeks ago and decided to load ubuntu on it now. After a hassle I was able to install the system on the pc by disabling a few boot options in the install screen of ubuntu(F6).

When I start the system up now it loads the usual orangy background but stays on that. No login no no nothing. The only way I managed to fix this was boot and load recovery mode and from there select "the top option" to continue the boot.

I don't mind this, as I know that nearly no one will figure out this process, so my pc will be secure. But the process is redundant and time consuming having to wait to time the shift keystroke perfectly.

Can anyone point me to a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution that i found on this one for my situation.

I had the 32bit installed on my system made 2 partitions for the system on my HD when I did this installation.

Later I decided I was going to try 64bit as my system supports this.

When I did this installation I did not partition the drive and installed ubuntu 64bit.
After this the boot problem was fixed. So either the non partitioning of the drive fixed this problem or the re-install of ubuntu 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try `fdisk` `sudo update-grub` and `sudo reboot`. Ubuntu 12.04 is still buggy. Hope, you can find more necessary information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165089/ubuntu-isnt-starting-after-unexpected-shutdown)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds similar to a problem that I had with one of my machines. It got resolved by installing the proprietary graphics card drivers (in my case from AMD). If your machine is connected to the Internet, you should be prompted to install restricted drivers. You can download the drivers manually from the following sites:

- [AMD drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx)
- [NVIDIA drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)

Comment: I have installed the drivers for my NVIDIA card, after the restart I had to go through the process again to get to the login screen.