# How to run Ubuntu after extracting the zip file to USB pen drive

Tags: windows, usb, usb-drive

I want to **install Ubuntu** in my **USB pen drive**. My current OS is **Windows 7** enterprise. I downloaded Ubuntu as zip file (using torrent) and I extracted the files to my USB pen drive. Now what should I do to run Ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'd check out [this answer about installing from a USB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164108/ubuntu-12-04-installation-issue/164146#164146) alternatively there are many other questions about installation on the site, have a look around, [this question about USB installation is probably the best](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick) hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I did it.
The problem was my computer will not automatically boot from pendrive. I should press the f5 button to boot. It is usually **f10** or **del**. I got **ubuntu** installed. Now I want to get my modem installed in ubuntu.
*http://askubuntu.com/questions/227496/how-to-install-wvdial-without-getting-the-following-error*