# How to install wvdial without getting the following error?

Tags: internet, usb-modem, wvdial

When I ran the command:

`sudo apt-get install wvdial`

I got this error message :

```
error
p@p:~$ sudo apt-get install wvdial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package wvdial is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package wvdial has no installation candidate
p@p:~$
```

**So how can I install wvdial?**

***BSNL EVDO Rev A USB Data Card Model No.:T-U500***

I don't have access to internet from Ubuntu for direct installation.

After I posted this question I got how to install wvdial and I installed it. Now I am facing another problem. I first took terminal and typed in `lsusb` after plugging my **modem (bsnl evdo data card)**. Then I typed `wvdialconf` and I got the following:

```
at@at-Presario-V3700-Notebook-PC:~$ lsusb

Bus 005 Device 002: ID 15eb:7153
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

at@at-Presario-V3700-Notebook-PC:~$ wvdialconf
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.
Scanning your serial ports for a modem.
ttyS0<Info>: Permission denied
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0
ttyS1<Info>: Permission denied
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S1
ttyS2<Info>: Permission denied
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S2
```

> !!CUT!!!

```
ttyS31<Info>: Permission denied
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S31
Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?
Please read the FAQ at http://alumnit.ca/wiki/?WvDial
```

**Can you help me in this? I want to install my modem.**

Comment: `sudo wvdialconf`

Comment: I think you're looking for usb_modeswitch: http://antipastohw.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-install-3g4g-cellular-modem-on.html

Comment: VISIT I got an error while trying to install my data card. Please help me to install that. http://askubuntu.com/questions/231665/install-bsnl-evdo-card-in-ubuntu-12-10 I tried that and got another error

Comment: Can I try the same for Ubuntu as in blog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the package using the computer that has connection to the Internet.

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/wvdial
```

Download the package appropiate for your architecture, i386 or amd64. I assume here you have Quantal; if not, choose another release.

After you put the package on the computer you want to install it run:

```
sudo dpkg -i package_file_name
```

e.g.,

```
sudo dpkg -i wvdial_1.61-4.1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: mountdevsf.sh. i am having this directory in home  and i want to edit it. how can i do that?

Comment: chndn: Have you read my comment in the main question? [:

Comment: "sudo wvdialconf" I get the same error : Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?
Please read the FAQ at http://alumnit.ca/wiki/?WvDial

Comment: Well, I guess it's your turn to read the FAQ. Maybe your problem will be solved there. If not, ask us again.

Comment: I used modprobe to get http://askubuntu.com/questions/231665/install-bsnl-evdo-card-in-ubuntu-12-10

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `apt-get` because you are not connected to the Internet. The  wvdial package and its dependencies are available on the Ubuntu Live CD; copy the files from there into a directory and use `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

Answer (score 2):

Check that at least the "main" repository is enabled at Ubuntu Software Center | Edit | Software Sources....  Then run `sudo apt-get update` and, if you get no error messages, try your command again.