# Install BSNL evdo card in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: internet, usb-modem

I want to install BSNL EVDO Rev A USB Data Card Model No.:T-U500 on my laptop which is double booted with both **ubuntu and windows 7**. BSNL evdo works well on windows 7 and I tried to install it on ubuntu.

I don't have internet connection in Ubuntu.

I tried to install using terminal

```
at@at-Presario-V3700-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x15eb product=0x7153
at@at-Presario-V3700-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo wvdialconf
```

Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

```
Scanning your serial ports for a modem.
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0   S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6   S7   
...
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- and failed too at 115200, giving up.
Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?
Please read the FAQ at http://alumnit.ca/wiki/?WvDial
```

TWO:
Then I tried to follow http://linuxers.org/howto/how-configure-bsnl-evdo-linux

And after I typed wvdial I am getting error `/etc/wvdial.conf` I edited to:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem=/dev/tty0
Baud=115200
Dial Command = ATDT
Baud=115200
Dial Command = ATDT
init1=ATZ
init2=AT+CRM=1
Flow Control= Hardware (CRTSCTS)
Username = 9180326472
Password = 9180326472
Phone = #777
Stupid Mode = 1
```

`resolv.conf` I edited to

```
hash Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
hash   DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 218.248.240.181
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

(By hash I mean #)

What I typed in terminal:

root@at-Presario-V3700-Notebook-PC:~# vim /etc/wvdial.conf
root@at-Presario-V3700-Notebook-PC:~# vim /etc/resolv.conf
root@at-Presario-V3700-Notebook-PC:~# wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
--> Sending: ATQ0
--> Re-Sending: ATZ
--> Modem not responding.
root@at-Presario-V3700-Notebook-PC:~#

After doing all this I logged into Windows, uninstalled it, unplugged the modem, plugged it again, clicked "open folder to view files", clicked Linux, Copied "BSNL EVDO Installer" to the desktop. Then I logged onto Ubuntu moved the file into its desktop and installed it. After installation I clicked "EVDO Data Card" but nothing happened. What should I do? Is the problem caused by something I did above?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install two software packages to make the internet connectivity work consistently without breaking. They are wvdial and gnome-ppp (The front-end tool to configure wvdial).

1) Install wvdial package

Open terminal,(alt+ctrl+t) and type the following command

`sudo apt-get install wvdial`

2) Install gnome-ppp

`sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp`

3) Open gnome-ppp from the terminal.

`sudo gnome-ppp`

4)You have to enter your BSNL 10-digit mobile number in the Username & your password. Type *99# in the number row. Then press the Setup button below.

5) In the Setup window below, click the “Detect” button to identify the device ID of the USB port in which you have inserted your USB modem. The tool would automatically detect the Device, Type and Speed of your USB modem. Once it has deteced, please the “Close” button below.

Once this is done click on Connect!!!

You could also configure it through the terminal. This [link](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2004/11/connecting-to-bsnl-dial-up-internet.html) should help you to configure it via terminal.

You could also try installing ixconn.you can get it [here](http://www.mwconn.net/download_ixconn.html)

Comment: whats the error you get?

Comment: No modem was found on your system

Comment: Do you have any other Operating system in your hard disk other than Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes WINDOWS 7 is also there

Comment: ok cool!now log into win7 first and insert the modem/dongle. Restart the computer and then log into ubuntu. but keep in mind that dont disconnect or eject the modem from pc and dont switch off the main power.
 Doing so You have to do the process again.

Comment: and then check if your device has been detected or no.This worked for me. Let me know if your device could be detected.

Comment: No it was not detected

Comment: @chndn - important information such as what you have tried should be added to your question - please do so and clean up by deleting your comments.  Thanks.

Comment: check out this site. http://ubuntuinstallation.blogspot.in/2011/03/ubuntu-bsnl-evdo.html install all the dependencies if there are any.

Comment: try following http://presoon.com/blog/2009/12/21/bsnl-evdo-connection-for-ubuntu-9-04-wvdial-missing-for-ubuntu/ incase you are still not able to install your modem.

Comment: QUESTION EDITED

Comment: Modem wont be detected if not using sudo.
To avoid this we can add the current user into dip and dialout user groups.
    sudo usermod -a -G dip [user-name]
    sudo usermod -a -G dialout [user-name]
After doing this, we may run gnome-ppp without sudo, as any normal application.
[Source](http://technobytz.com/how-to-install-bsnl-evdo-in-ubuntu-mint-in-3-minutes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Mobile Broadband in the network menu? Once you enable it, a wizard will pop up to add your dongle. Choose India and then BSNL and choose your appropriate plan. I followed the same procedure for my Reliance 3G dongle. No need for the terminal at least in my case. Ubuntu installed all the relevant packages automatically.