# How to install BSNL evdo U500 data card in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, internet, usb-modem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install BSNL evdo card in Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231665/install-bsnl-evdo-card-in-ubuntu-12-10)

I am having a ***BSNL EVDO Rev A USB Data Card Model No.:T-U500*** and want to install it in my Ubuntu which **has no internet connection.** What should I do?

I have asked similar questions in:
[How to install wvdial without getting the following error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227496/how-to-install-wvdial-without-getting-the-following-error/)
[Install BSNL evdo card in Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231665/install-bsnl-evdo-card-in-ubuntu-12-10)

You may refer them